# React Native: Fetched data wont render as an object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, expo

I have the below code to dynamically render a component with data from an API. However I keep getting this error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

In the code I tried to create an array with the data but still continue to get the error. There is just one object that I extract from the API data to render.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, Image, TextInput, StyleSheet, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo-av';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default async function Profile({navigation}) {

  const [company, setCompany] = useState([])


const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('company')
    console.log(value)
      fetchData(value)
    if(value !== null) {
    }
  } catch(e) {
  }
}
  const fetchData = (name) => {
    fetch("https://stonernautz.com/companies.json")
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
  
        for(var i in data){
          if(data[i].name == name)
            console.log(data[i])
            setCompany("["+JSON.stringify(data[i])+"]")
            console.log(company)
        }
      })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
   getData()
  });
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor:"black",color:"white"}}>
      <View style={styles.catView}>
  <Ionicons name="arrow-back" color={'white'} size={26} style={{marginLeft:0, marginTop:10}} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}/>
  <Text style={{color:"white"}}>Back</Text>
  </View>
    <View style={{height:"60%",position:'absolute', top:110}}>
<ScrollView>
{company.map(user => (
            <View style={{marginBottom:100}} key={user.name}>
                <Video
                source={{ uri: `${user.video}` }}
                rate={1.0}
                volume={1.0}
                isMuted={false}
                resizeMode="contain"
                useNativeControls

                style={{ width: 400, height: 250, maxWidth:"100%" }}
                /> 
                <Image
            style ={styles.image}
            source={{ uri : `${user.logo}`}}
          />
                <Text style={styles.name}>{user.name}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        
      >
        <Text>Connect</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
          ))}
    </ScrollView>
           </View>




           </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderBottomColor: '#000000',
    borderTopColor: '#000000',
    borderRightColor: '#000000',
    borderLeftColor: '#000000',
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: "#000000"
  },
  image: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 100,
    overflow: "hidden",
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft:20
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 10,
    width:200,
    position:'absolute',
    top:300,
    left:'25%',
    height:40,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop:10,
  },
  scrollView: {
    position:'absolute',
    top:80,
    left:0,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    maxHeight:400,
    width:"90%",
    maxWidth:"100%",


  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 100,
     marginLeft:10,

  },
  catText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize:24,
    marginLeft:40,
    lineHeight:50


  },
  catView: {
paddingRight: 20,
position:"absolute",
top:50,
left:20
  },
  name: {
    color:'white',
    fontSize:20,
    position:'absolute',
    top:260,
    left:110,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'

  },
});
```

Comment: Call getData in `useEffect`.

Comment: @iphonic your solution did not work.

Comment: I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

getData is async so you should try to await the Promise with something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   (async () => {
       await getData()
   })();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after A While, Here is what I did:

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, Image, TextInput, StyleSheet, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo-av';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderBottomColor: '#000000',
    borderTopColor: '#000000',
    borderRightColor: '#000000',
    borderLeftColor: '#000000',
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: "#000000"
  },
  image: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 100,
    overflow: "hidden",
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft:20
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 10,
    width:200,
    position:'absolute',
    top:300,
    left:'25%',
    height:40,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop:10,
  },
  scrollView: {
    position:'absolute',
    top:80,
    left:0,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    maxHeight:400,
    width:"90%",
    maxWidth:"100%",


  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 100,
     marginLeft:10,

  },
  catText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize:24,
    marginLeft:40,
    lineHeight:50


  },
  catView: {
paddingRight: 20,
position:"absolute",
top:50,
left:20
  },
  name: {
    color:'white',
    fontSize:20,
    position:'absolute',
    top:260,
    left:110,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'

  },
});




class ProductList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      company: []
    }
  }
fetchData = (company) => {
    //console.log("hi"+ company)
    fetch("https://stonernautz.com/companies.json")
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
  
        for(var i in data){
          if(data[i].name == company){
            this.setState({ company: data[i] })
            //console.log(this.state)
          }
        }
      })
    }
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('company')
    //console.log(value)

    await this.fetchData(value)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor:"black", height:"100%", alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center"}}>
      <Text style={{color:"white", alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center"}}>{this.state.company.name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
} 

export default ProductList;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).